# Avoiding overlapping superscripts and subscripts in matrices

Tags: matrices, subscripts, superscripts

I was working on some calculus today and tried to typeset a matrix of partial derivatives and ran into some trouble. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_1}   & \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_2}\\
    \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_1}   & \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_2}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

As can be seen, the output results in the subscripts from the denominators of the top row on the matrix with the superscripts from the numerators of the bottom row on the matrix. Is there an easy way to avoid this?

Comment: `\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}`  just before `\begin{pmatrix}`.

Comment: While that certainly helps, is there a way to do it only for some of the lines of the matrix?

Comment: Use the optional argument of ` \\ ` as in `\\[20pt]`.

Comment: Yes, you can pad rows using struts or by increasing the row's vertical spacing with respect to the others using ``\\[<len>]``. This is described in [Column and row padding in tables](http://goo.gl/X3kPH).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column and row padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables)

Comment: @Werner I'm not sure that question applies for this case. That one deals with very different cases and it may be difficult to find the good way out for matrices.

Comment: @egreg: It deals with many (general) cases of padding (horizontally/vertically). While it may be difficult, it also seems like it could be user-preference as to whether a global or per-row/-column adjustment should be performed. For me, the this post is covered in the more general (linked) duplicate.

Comment: @Werner Nothing in the answers suggests the methods are valid also for `matrix` like environments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `cellspace` package defines 2 lengths, `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit` that are the minimal vertical white space between the top of a cell and the bottom of the above cell, and between the bottom of a cell and the top of the below cell. Here is a example:

```
    \documentclass{minimal}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \usepackage[math]{cellspace}
    \cellspacetoplimit 3pt
    \cellspacebottomlimit 3pt
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \dfrac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_1}   & \dfrac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_2}\\
        \dfrac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_1}   & \dfrac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_2}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \]

    \cellspacetoplimit 0pt
    \cellspacebottomlimit 0pt
    \[
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \dfrac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_1}   & \dfrac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_2}\\
        \dfrac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_1}   & \dfrac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_2}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \]
    \end{document}
```

[image]

It works with the amsmath environments (matrix, &c.), but not, unfortunately, with their starred versions defined by `mathtools`.

Comment: What does the optional math argument change for the cellspace package?

Comment: Without it, it works only for tabular and the like (text mode, I guess).

Comment: Ok. Additionally, is there a way to set the length using more flexible length parameters such as `1em` or `2ex`? I'd like it to be variable based on the size of my text if possible.

Comment: I've just tested: the answer is no. But I can ask the author if it would be possible.

Comment: I forgot to mention that if one has to ask specifically the math option, the reason is that it tackles an internal command of the matrix environments (the \env@matrix command). So `amsmath`, `empheq`and `mathtools`h ave to be loaded _before_ cellspace.

Answer (score 11):

One way is to use the optional argument of `\\` like `\\[<length>]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_1}   & \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_2}\\[1ex]
    \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_1}   & \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_2}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Another way is to add one invisible line with `0` width, `-2ex` depth (say) and `4ex` total height in the first row.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
    \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{4ex}\frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_1}   & \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_2}\\
    \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_1}   & \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_2}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With a TABstack, you have complete control over the horizontal and vertical spacing.  Here are two examples.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\setstackgap{L}{1.6\baselineskip}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\parenMatrixstack{
    \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_1}   & \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_2}\\
    \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_1}   & \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_2}
}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\setstackgap{L}{1.8\baselineskip}
\setstacktabbedgap{1.4ex}
\parenMatrixstack{
    \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_1}   & \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x_2}\\
    \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_1}   & \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_2}
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]